# C++ TCP Client - accept a floating point number and a mathematical operator

Tags: c++

This is what I need help accomplishing: Prompt the user and accept a floating point number, Prompt the user and accept a mathematical operator (+, - *, /), Prompt the user and accept another floating point number. This is my client code. I have a server code which I need this program to send the data to for processing and then display the results. I can post my server code if it's needed. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock.h>

// Function prototype
void StreamClient(char *szServer, short nPort);

// Helper macro for displaying errors
#define PRINTERROR(s)   \
        fprintf(stderr,"\n%s: %d\n", s, WSAGetLastError())

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(1,1);
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int nRet;
    short nPort;

    //
    // Check for the host and port arguments
    //
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nSyntax: TCPTimeClient ServerName PortNumber\n");
        return;
    }

    nPort = atoi(argv[2]);

    //
    // Initialize WinSock and check the version
    //
    nRet = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (wsaData.wVersion != wVersionRequested)
    {   
        fprintf(stderr,"\n Wrong version\n");
        return;
    }

    //
    // Go do all the stuff a datagram client does
    //
    StreamClient(argv[1], nPort);

    //
    // Release WinSock resources
    //
    WSACleanup();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void StreamClient(char *szServer, short nPort)
{
    int nRet;                       // return code
    char szBuf[256];                // client buffer area 
    char szSvr[256];                // server name

    LPHOSTENT lpHostEntry;          // host data structure
    SOCKET  theSocket;              // client socket
    SOCKADDR_IN saClient;           // socket address structure

    //
    // Get local machine name
    //
    nRet = gethostname(szSvr, sizeof(szSvr));

    //
    // Check for errors
    //
    if (nRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        PRINTERROR("gethostname()");
        return;
    }

    // 
    // Display an informational message
    //
    printf("Datagram Client [%s] sending to server [%s] on port %d...\n",
                                szSvr, szServer, nPort);

    //
    // Find the server
    //
    lpHostEntry = gethostbyname(szServer);
    if (lpHostEntry == NULL)
    {
        PRINTERROR("gethostbyname()");
        return;
    }

    //
    // Create a TCP/IP datagram socket
    //
    theSocket = socket(AF_INET,         // Address family
                       SOCK_STREAM,     // Socket type
                       0);              // Protocol

    //
    // Check for errors
    //
    if (theSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        PRINTERROR("socket()");
        return;
    }

    //
    // Fill in the address structure of the server
    //
    saClient.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saClient.sin_addr = *((LPIN_ADDR)*lpHostEntry->h_addr_list);
                                        // ^ Client's address
    saClient.sin_port = htons(nPort);   // Port number from command line

    //
    // Connect to the server
    //
    nRet = connect(theSocket, 
            (struct sockaddr *)&saClient, 
            sizeof(saClient));

    //
    // Check for errors
    //
    if(nRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
      PRINTERROR("Connect()");
      return;
    }

    //
    // Prepare some data to send to the server
    //
    sprintf(szBuf, "From the Client [%s]", szSvr);

    //
    // Send data to the server
    //
    nRet = send(theSocket,                  // Socket
                  szBuf,                    // Data buffer
                  (int)strlen(szBuf),       // Length of data
                  0);                       // Flags

    //
    // Check for errors
    //
    if (nRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        PRINTERROR("send()");
        closesocket(theSocket);
        return;
    }

    //
    // Zero out the incoming data buffer
    //
    memset(szBuf, 0, sizeof(szBuf));

    //
    // Wait for the reply
    //
    nRet = recv(theSocket,                  // Socket
                szBuf,                      // Receive buffer
                sizeof(szBuf),              // Length of receive buffer
                0);                         // Flags

    //
    // Check for errors
    //
    if (nRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        PRINTERROR("recv()");
        closesocket(theSocket);
        return;
    }

    //
    // Display the data that was received
    //
    printf("\n%s", szBuf);

    //
    // Close the socket
    //
    closesocket(theSocket);
    return;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I don't know how to prompt the user to enter a floating number and a mathematical operator

Comment: @JSQuareD So I don't know how to proceed

Comment: I added an answer to explain I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Your networking code looks good, although I'm not an expert on that part. Prompting the user for input is quite easy. Since you used C-style I/O in your question, I will use C-style I/O as well, even though your question is tagged `C++`.

To write output to the console, use `printf`:

```
printf("\nPlease enter a floating point number: ");
```

(`\n` will output a newline.)

To read output from the console, use `scanf`:

```
float number1;
scanf("%f", &number1);
```

Here the string `"%f"` indicates that we are reading a floating point number. The second argument is a pointer to a floating point number in which we want to store our answer. For more information about `scanf`, see the [cplusplus-reference](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

You can prompt for the other input in a similar fashion. Complete code:

```
printf("\nPlease enter a floating point number: ");
float number1;
scanf("%f", &number1);

printf("\nPlease enter a mathematical operator (+,-,*,/): ");
char mathOperator;
scanf("%c", &mathOperator);
if( mathOperator != '+' && mathOperator!= '-' && mathOperator!= '*' && mathOperator!= '/' )
{
    //your error handling here
}

printf("\nPlease enter a floating point number: ");
float number2;
scanf("%f", &number2);

printf("\nCalculating %f %c %f...", &number1, &mathOperator, &number2);

//now send data to server
```

In the latest example of `printf`, you can also see that you can write values to the output in a fashion similar to how you read them, and that you can have multiple values in a single command. For more information on `printf`, see the [cplusplus-reference](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: thanks for the help! Few questions though, this part printf("\nCalculating %f %c %f...", %number1, &mathOperator, &number2); I had to get rid of the "%" in %number1 and replaced it with a "&" to get it to run. Is this ok? Also, I can enter the first floating number, but for some reason I don't have an option to enter the math operator. It displays that but skips it and asks for the next floating number and then it exits without doing anything else. Here is a screenshot to explain better. Thanks again  http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/445/helpfloat.jpg

Comment: @JeffFisher The `%` in front of `number1` was a typo, and you were right to replace it with `&`. I edited my answer accordingly. I'm not sure why getting the operator isn't working, I'm used to C++-I/O. Try replacing the `scanf`-part with `c=getchar()`.

Comment: I tried c=getchar() with no luck. Then I tried changing scanf("%c", &mathOperator); to scanf("%f", &mathOperator); and for some reason that did the trick. Now the next question is how to get a response from the server? I can enter 1 plus 1 for example.. but then it closes. I need to send to the server for processing. I'm sorry I'm taking so much of your time but again I appreciate your help. I'm a lot farther now than what I could have ever done

Comment: any idea on what I can do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @JeffFisher You already have code for sending and receiving data. Just use that but with the entered data instead of command line arguments or w/e.